# NameError while loading contents of a npz file in python

Tags: python, numpy, load, list-comprehension

I am trying to load numpy files from a npz file. When I try to load the numpy files I get NameError.

Below is what is have tried. I create a sample npz file from a list of 2 numpy files. I load the npz file. I extract the numpy files from the npz file. This is where I get `NameError`. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong with the list comprehension or the way I am loading the npz file is incorrect.

```
ipdb> data = [np.arange(8).reshape(4,2), np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)]
ipdb> np.savez('mat.npz', *data)
ipdb> dat = np.load('mat.npz')
ipdb> ind = [dat[k] for k in dat.keys()]
```

I am getting below error:
`*** NameError: name 'dat' is not defined`

Comment: Have you tried it without the debugger?  Or `list(dat.values())`?

Comment: @hpaulj the code works outside of debugger, and `ipdb> list(dat.values())` gives an error `*** Error in argument: '(dat.values())'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried same code and didn't got any error

```
    import numpy as np
    data = [np.arange(8).reshape(4,2), np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)]
    np.savez('mat.npz', *data)
    dat = np.load('mat.npz')
    ind = [dat[k] for k in dat.keys()]
    print(ind)
```

Output:

```
 [array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]]), array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])]
```

It guess it's the issue with IPython.Check this article https://github.com/inducer/pudb/issues/103

Comment: or more specifically the `ipdb` REPL, not the regular `ipython` REPL.